# Calculating the value of attributes of cards in a card game

Tags: bayesian, games, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons

I hope this is a stats question :) There's a game (RftG) with cards, each of which has various attributes (generally bonuses of some kind) and a price. I'm wondering if there's some kind of technique for determining the average value of each attribute, and therefore calculating the expected cost of each card as a whole, and therefore finding "undervalued" and "overpriced" cards.

Now, say that each attribute is a letter (A, B, C...), an obvious and simple technique would be to look for minimal pairs:

ABC: $5

ABCD: $7

E: $1

ED: $2

Therefore D has an average value of $1.50

But that seems far too simple and limited. For starters, not every attribute will turn up in a minimal pair. Can anyone point me in the right direction of the kind of technique that would work here? I'm afraid I don't have a stats background. Even some relevant stats terms would help.

If interested, there's a card list here: 
http://boardgamegeek.com/file/download/4wl2eqaevk/RftG_%2B_exp1_%2B_exp2_%2B_Card_Reference_v1.0.xls

Comment: nice idea (a general problem I wondered about when I was playing Magic the Gathering). a) I checked out the excel-file. It seems that the price-column is missing. Or did I overlook something ? b) the prices are trade-prices, aren't they ? In this case the prices are not related to the value of the card attributes (but number of prints) ?

Comment: Sorry for misused terms. With "value of card attributes" I meant something like "attack has the value 3" not the estimated money-value of "attack=3".

Comment: still there ? It would be nice if you could add some prices, I'd like to play around a litte bit (which may lead to a solution ...)

Answer (score 1):

Regression analysis could be used for this sort of thing. But it wouldn't be perfect. For one reason, regression analysis is meant for random data, and the prices fixed to playing cards is definitely not random.

There's not really a standard method here. One reason is that certain abilities, in different contexts become more valuable, and a combination of abilities can be more powerful than if the two abilities were on separate cards.

Comment: Part of your answer seems to have been deleted.

Comment: >a combination of abilities can be more powerful than if the two abilities were on separate cards.

Yeah, I was hoping for a method that could yield answers like:
v(X) = 1.6

v(X,Y)=0.2

...

Or even functions where the result depends on another variable.

Comment: You can do that sort of thing with regression analysis, it just starts to get really complicated. Doing a full regression analysis would require a package of statistical software as well as some sort of digital file containing all of the card info.